# How to remove the hash from the url in react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using react-router for my routing and I use the hashHistory option so that I could refresh the page from the browser or specify a url of one of my existing routes and land on the right page.
It works fine but I see the hash in the url like this:
http://localhost/#/login?_k=ya6z6i

This is my routing configuration:

```
ReactDOM.render((
 <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path='/' component={MasterPage}>
      <IndexRoute component={LoginPage} />
      <Route path='/search' component={SearchPage} />
      <Route path='/login' component={LoginPage} />
      <Route path='/payment' component={PaymentPage} />
    </Route>
  </Router>),
    document.getElementById('app-container'));
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Did you try the browserHistory option ? You will be able also to refresh the page from the browser or specify a url of one of existing routes and land on the right page.

```
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

ReactDOM.render((
 <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path='/' component={MasterPage}>
      <IndexRoute component={LoginPage} />
      <Route path='/search' component={SearchPage} />
      <Route path='/login' component={LoginPage} />
      <Route path='/payment' component={PaymentPage} />
    </Route>
  </Router>),
    document.getElementById('app-container'));
```

Moreover hashHistory is not for production use considering the react-router github doc.

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md#browserhistory

**Should I use hashHistory?**

> Hash history works without configuring your server, so if you're just
>   getting started, go ahead and use it. But, we don't recommend using it
>   in production, every web app should aspire to use browserHistory

Comment: i tried it and the hash disappeared. However i cannot land on the same page after browser refresh

Comment: Do you use a server (node.js) to serve your files ?

Comment: It should work if the first time you make a request to the server let's say at mysite.com you serve an index.html file when you click on a button that invoke the router mysite.com/page1 it will show the page using react router on the client side. But when you it refresh it ask the server the URL mysite.com/page1 but if you serve for every request the index.html file with a pattern like * on every request i serve index.html you should see the right content because mysite.com/page1 -> give index.html but the react router see /page1 and do the job like you clicked yourself again on page1 button.

Comment: `browserHistory` need server side rendering. so I use `hashHistory` in production, because I won't need server side rendering in my project.

Comment: If you want to use `react-router-dom` with `history`, 
use: `import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';`

Comment: In react-router-dom v6 you can use BrowserRouter for remove #

Answer (score 12):

i am new to react but i have used BrowserRouter and it works fine :-

```
    import React from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter >
    <Switch>
      {indexRoutes.map((prop, key) => {
        return <Route to={prop.path} component={prop.component} key={key} />;
      })}
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Answer (score 5):

I believe it was mentioned above by Dennis Nerush, you need to use {browserHistory} instead of {hashHistory}, however for the same page rendering to work you need to configure your server a bit to allow for this.

Depending on where you are hosted or what server you are using there are a few ways to do this

For **Apache** you must add the following to the .htaccess (or create .htaccess and place it in the root folder of your website):

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

For Node.js/ Express you need to add the following code:

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'path/to/your/index.html'), function(err) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err)
    }
  })
})
```

for Nginx servers you need to add the following to the Nginx.conf file

```
location / {
  if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.html break;
  }
}
```

For Amplify you need to go to Rewrites & Redirects and add a new rule that with the following information (Note I have only used this on AWS):

```
Source address: </^[^.]+$|\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf)$)([^.]+$)/>
Target address: /index.html
Type: 200
```

Here are a few links if you want to do some more research on the subject.

https://www.andreasreiterer.at/fix-browserrouter-on-apache/#comment-186 (Specifically for Apache)

https://ui.dev/react-router-cannot-get-url-refresh/ (Multiple methods for different servers or no server which I did not add above)

[React Router DOM not working correctly on Amplify Console AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57449853/react-router-dom-not-working-correctly-on-amplify-console-aws) (Use this one for AWS and Amplify)

Answer (score 3):

You will need to import `browserHistory` from `react-router` 
and pass it to the `<Router />` in order to remove the hash from the URL

Ex:

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

<Router history={browserHistory}>
 //Place your route here
</Router>
```

Comment: Module '"react-router"' has no exported member 'browserHistory'.ts(2305)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// v1.x
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory'
<Router history={createBrowserHistory()} />

// v2.0.0
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'
<Router history={browserHistory} />


const history = createHashHistory({ queryKey: false });
<Router history={history}>
</Router>
```

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md#using-custom-histories

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/8ef625e8fa7c41dda0f3d1d68a10b74bd93a4101/docs/guides/ba...

Comment: have guess why I got this error without even using react-router? just react and react-dom

Comment: What about 3.x? `You have provided a history object created with history v2.x or earlier. This version of React Router is only compatible with v3 history objects. Please upgrade to history v3.x.`

Comment: ok fixed with this `import { createHistory } from 'history'; // you need to install this package
let history = createHistory();`