# Grunt dev server to allow push states

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I am trying to set up my grunt server to allow push states.

After countless google searches and reading SO posts I cannot figure out how to do this.

I keep getting errors like the one below.

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

> No "connect" targets found. Warning: Task "connect" failed. Use --force to continue.

It appears to me below that I have defined `targets` with the line

```
open: {
    target: 'http://localhost:8000'
 }
```

See complete code below:

```
var pushState = require('grunt-connect-pushstate/lib/utils').pushState;

module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        connect: {
        options: {
          hostname: 'localhost',
          port: 8000,
          keepalive: true,
          open: {
             target: 'http://localhost:8000'
          },
          middleware: function (connect, options) {
            return [
              // Rewrite requests to root so they may be handled by router 
              pushState(),

              // Serve static files 
              connect.static(options.base)
            ];
          } 
        }
      }
    });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify'); // Load the plugin that provides the "uglify" task.
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect'); // Load the plugin that provides the "connect" task.

  // Default task(s).
  grunt.registerTask('default', [ 'connect']);

};
```

Comment: Situations like this are why I switched to `gulp`.  Also, the package is depricated.

Comment: @MichaelCole running into the same issues with `gulp`! any ideas of how to do it with `gulp`? It appears that not even google knows!

Comment: Sorry, I can't help.  This is pretty old tech - I've built MEAN apps and didn't need this.  Are you sure you need it?

Comment: I want a way of allowing push states on my local server. Do you know any other way of getting around this? I am no expert

Answer (score 0):

Push states are already included in most SPA frameworks, so you might not need this unless you're building a framework.

Angular: https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag

React: [How to remove the hash from the url in react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35181989/how-to-remove-the-hash-from-the-url-in-react-router)

This looks like a grunt build script to compile an application to serve.  So I'm not exactly sure how you'd use pushStates in the build process.  You may be trying to solve the wrong problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother with grunt to deploy a local dev pushstate server for your SPA.

In your project directory, install https://www.npmjs.com/package/pushstate-server

`npm i pushstate-server -D`

Then to launch it, add a `script` entry in the package.json of your project:

`…
"scripts": {
    "dev": "pushstate-server"
}
…`

This way you can now start it running `npm run dev`

All the requests which would normally end in a 404 will now redirect to `index.html`.