# how use router in reactjs without hashtag and in asp.net mvc with refresh page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs

[How to remove the hash from the url in react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35181989/how-to-remove-the-hash-from-the-url-in-react-router)

Comment: You need to clarify and further explain your question in order to receive a proper answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the hash from the url in react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35181989/how-to-remove-the-hash-from-the-url-in-react-router)

Answer (score 0):

Generally you'll have to use the `browserHistory` instead of `hashHistory` in ReactRouter, but then the difficulty comes in the ASP.NET side of things.  A quick google pulled up [this tutorial](https://howtoember.wordpress.com/2016/06/04/using-react-router-with-asp-net-mvc/).