# How can i stop "#" added after my react local link?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

i am new in react and trying to create App with sub-pages no issue with that i have done it but one small issue is my link "**localhost:3000/**" converted in "**localhost:3000/#/**"

Here is my code:

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from './layouts/header.js';
import Footer from './layouts/footer.js';
import Sidebar from './layouts/sidebar.js';
import './css/style.scss';


  const App = (props) => {

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="sideBar">
          <Sidebar />
        </div>
        <div className="main_container">
          <Header />
            {props.children}
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </div>
    );

}

export default App;
```

routes.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';


/**
 * Import all page components here
 */
import App from './App.js';
import MainPage from './pages/homepage.js';
import About from './pages/about.js';

/**
 * All routes go here.
 * Don't forget to import the components above after adding new route.*/

export default (
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={MainPage} />
      <Route path="/about/:id" component={About} />
    </Route>
  );
```

Comment: Use `BrowserRouter`.

Comment: @HarishSoni Please have look my code i think i m doing something different,
i dont want to use Link

Comment: @jaykhatri plz post the code here.

Comment: @jaykhatri, first of all, please post your router code here.

Comment: I have already attached my all  code and mention google link in my question

Answer (score 0):

Try with **browserHistory**

```
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router';


<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
   <IndexRoute component={MainPage} />
   <Route path="/about/:id" component={About} />
  </Route>
</Router>
```

Reference: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35181989/how-to-remove-the-hash-from-the-url-in-react-router)