# How to remove # in URL of .NET Core when it's using app.UseFileServer() to serve react build production

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core

Is there are any way to remove `#` in URL of .NET Core project? My project is using `app.UseFileServer()` to serve react application (production/build from react app) inside wwwroot. It is working properly if only we acess the root URL of .NET Core that serves using IIS, for example:

```
https://yourdomain.com
```

But if we want to go to the route of react for example route about, it needs a URL like this:

```
https://yourdomain.com/#/about
```

I don't know why the `#` sign should be there, is there are any way to make the URL like this:

```
https://yourdomain.com/about
```

so it directly accesses the route `about` of react?

Comment: _"I dont know why the # sign should be there"_ - because everything after the `#` is called the fragment, and that doesn't get sent to the server. If it does, it's part of the path. Either configure all paths except a (directory) whitelist (for static resources) to your index.html, or leave it that way?

Answer (score 0):

You are using hashHistory routing in react app. In the case if you want to remove # please use browserHistory routing
for more detail check this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35185338/7327166

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but actually it serves properly without # if I serve using node js with command of npm start.