# React router works only with /#/ within the URL, otherwise error 404 on a Ubuntu server

Tags: reactjs, linux, nginx, react-router

My app is deployed (`npm run build`)  on a Ubuntu server.
I'm using a Router in my App and when clicking on a link (i.e contact-us), it's working - user is redirected to the page.

But if I'm trying to access to the **contact-us** page directly (http://my_ip/contact-us), I get a 404 response.

**Note:** If I add a /#/ to the url, it does work! i.e http://my_ip/#/contact-us.

Some code:

```
 import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
    import history from './history';
    
        render() {
            return (
              <div className="page">
                <Router history={history}>
                <Header />
                  <Switch>
                    <Route path="/combination/:some_id" exact component={SomePage} />
                    <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
                    <Route path="/contact-us" exact component={ContactUs} />
                  </Switch>
                </Router>
              </div>
            )
          }
```

History.js:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export default createBrowserHistory();
```

**Update**
The problem was Nginx configuration: Adding the following line solved it.

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
```

But now the problem is for the first Route (SomePage),

I just see a blank page!  No error 404. what does it mean?

Comment: Yep, you are using the HashRouter https://reactrouter.com/web/api/HashRouter You must use the BrowserRouter https://reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter

Comment: @NoNickAvailable Thanks, I'll try! Does it matter if I put it in index.js or App.js?

Comment: You must only change the import to 'BrowserRouter as Router'

Comment: Not working. still the same

Comment: what is the history variable you are using there ? is it createBrowserHistory  ?

Comment: yes :import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export default createBrowserHistory();

Comment: What version of react router are you using?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time:) "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",

Comment: No problem. I think your import is wrong: correct createBrowserHistory to only browserHistory. And you can directly import it together with BrowserRouter in one line. Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35185338/8605830

Comment: No.. it doesn't help. Maybe it's something with nginx...

Comment: @NoNickAvailable could you please look at my updated answer?

Comment: Is the problem for ://my_ip or also for ://my_ip/ ?

Comment: @NoNickAvailable  no, Only for that specific url template  /combination/:some_id